# spark-streaming and connection pool implementation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

The spark-streaming website at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams mentions the following code:

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
    // ConnectionPool is a static, lazily initialized pool of connections
    val connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection()
    partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
    ConnectionPool.returnConnection(connection)  // return to the pool for future reuse
  }
}
```

I have tried to implement this using org.apache.commons.pool2 but running the application fails with the expected java.io.NotSerializableException:

```
15/05/26 08:06:21 ERROR OneForOneStrategy: org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
 ...
```

I am wondering how realistic it is to implement a connection pool that is serializable. Has anyone succeeded in doing this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To address this "local resource" problem what's needed is a singleton object - i.e. an object that's warranted to be instantiated once and only once in the JVM. Luckily, Scala `object` provides this functionality out of the box.

The second thing to consider is that this singleton will provide a service to all tasks running on the same JVM where it's hosted, so, it *MUST* take care of concurrency and resource management.

Let's try to sketch(*) such service:

```scala
class ManagedSocket(private val pool: ObjectPool, val socket:Socket) {
   def release() = pool.returnObject(socket)
}

// singleton object 
object SocketPool {
    var hostPortPool:Map[(String, Int),ObjectPool] = Map()
    sys.addShutdownHook{
        hostPortPool.values.foreach{ // terminate each pool } 
    }

    // factory method
    def apply(host:String, port:String): ManagedSocket = {
        val pool = hostPortPool.getOrElse{(host,port), {
            val p = ??? // create new pool for (host, port)
            hostPortPool += (host,port) -> p
            p
        }
        new ManagedSocket(pool, pool.borrowObject)
    }
}
```

Then usage becomes:

```
val host = ???
val port = ???
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    rdd.foreachPartition { partition => 
        val mSocket = SocketPool(host, port)
        partition.foreach{elem => 
            val os = mSocket.socket.getOutputStream()
            // do stuff with os + elem
        }
        mSocket.release()
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that the `GenericObjectPool` used in the question is taking care of concurrency. Otherwise, access to each `pool` instance need to be guarded with some form of synchronization.

(*) code provided to illustrate the idea on how to design such object - needs additional effort to be converted into a working version.

Comment: This approach seems to work. Thanks a bunch. I'm flagging it as the preferred answer. For a concrete implementation of this answer see https://gist.github.com/koen-dejonghe/39c10357607c698c0b04

Comment: It's better to use a ThreadLocal in Java instead of a Singleton. With ThreadLocal you have an instance per thread so you avoid concurrency problems.

Comment: @CarlosVerdes depends on your needs. If implementing a cache, having a ThreadLocal instance will mean duplicating data n times the number of possible threads using that code path. If you just need to remember a small dataset or a resource (like a connection in this case), it could be an option.

Comment: Shouldn't the Map be concurrent and the pool entries created in an atomic fashion with `putIfAbsent`?

Comment: this solution is ok. however, why would we need a pool there? we get connection per partition, and normally it's one thread per partition, so there won't be more that one connection per partition anyway. the object as singleton is good since the main purpose there is to reuse connection per micro-batch in spark streaming. so we don't recreate DBdao every microbatch(which will be bad in short interval streaming case).

Answer (score 3):

**Below answer is wrong!**
I'm leaving the answer here for reference, but the answer is wrong for the following reason. `socketPool` is declared as a `lazy val` so it will get instantiated with each first request for access. Since the SocketPool case class is not `Serializable`, this means that it will get instantiated within each partition. Which makes the connection pool useless because we want to keep connections across partitions and RDDs. It makes no difference wether this is implemented as a companion object or as a case class. Bottom line is: the connection pool must be `Serializable`, and apache commons pool is not.

```
import java.io.PrintStream
import java.net.Socket

import org.apache.commons.pool2.{PooledObject, BasePooledObjectFactory}
import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.{DefaultPooledObject, GenericObjectPool}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream

/**
 * Publish a Spark stream to a socket.
 */
class PooledSocketStreamPublisher[T](host: String, port: Int)
  extends Serializable {

    lazy val socketPool = SocketPool(host, port)

    /**
     * Publish the stream to a socket.
     */
    def publishStream(stream: DStream[T], callback: (T) => String) = {
        stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>

            rdd.foreachPartition { partition =>

                val socket = socketPool.getSocket
                val out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream)

                partition.foreach { event =>
                    val text : String = callback(event)
                    out.println(text)
                    out.flush()
                }

                out.close()
                socketPool.returnSocket(socket)

            }
        }
    }

}

class SocketFactory(host: String, port: Int) extends BasePooledObjectFactory[Socket] {

    def create(): Socket = {
        new Socket(host, port)
    }

    def wrap(socket: Socket): PooledObject[Socket] = {
        new DefaultPooledObject[Socket](socket)
    }

}

case class SocketPool(host: String, port: Int) {

    val socketPool = new GenericObjectPool[Socket](new SocketFactory(host, port))

    def getSocket: Socket = {
        socketPool.borrowObject
    }

    def returnSocket(socket: Socket) = {
        socketPool.returnObject(socket)
    }

}
```

which you can invoke as follows:

```
val socketStreamPublisher = new PooledSocketStreamPublisher[MyEvent](host = "10.10.30.101", port = 29009)
socketStreamPublisher.publishStream(myEventStream, (e: MyEvent) => Json.stringify(Json.toJson(e)))
```

Comment: Actually, you would like to make your pool  an  `object`, which is a singleton for each JVM where executors are running. That way, the initialization will only happen once and it can keep state (like sockets in use) between Spark tasks.

Comment: How do I make properties like host and port configurable in an object ? Because that is exactly why I am using a case class rather than an object.

Comment: Your note is correct - this version will reinstantiate the pool for each interation of the mapPartitions on each executor - I found few minutes to sketch a solution that would work; see answer.